# Как настраивать, запускать и останавливать сетевые интерфейсы в C++ приложении Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, сеть, wifi, ethernet

Я ищу способ управления конфигурацией сети из под C++ приложения.

Как пример того что мне нужно:

1. Получение IP-адреса с использованием dhcp или наоборот установка статического ip.
2. Установка маски и шлюза.
3. Запуск и остановка сетевых интерфейсов(типа wlan0, eth0).

Также:

4. Могу ли я использовать QT для этого, и если да, где я мог бы найти примеры?

До сих пор я использовал /etc/network/interfaces и ifup/ifdown для подключения/отключения от сетей WiFi и Ethernet, но этот метод довольно неудобен, потому что он не всегда дает правильные результаты, и вызывает исключения и ошибки, которые трудно потом обработать.

Система, на которой это должно работать - Ubuntu разных версий.

Comment: Network Manager https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/

Comment: @GarfieldCat спасибо за ответ, но что-то с этой библиотекой траблы со сборкой:    ```/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gdbusintrospection.h:155:24: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   GDBusSignalInfo     **signals;
                        ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gdbusintrospection.h:155:32: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘;’ token
   GDBusSignalInfo     **signals;
                                ^```

Comment: так она же доступна в репозиориях https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/libnm-dev

Comment: @GarfieldCat именно оттуда и брал, но что-то идет не так

Comment: Рассказывайте как устанавливали, как компилируете. Вот пример использования https://developer.gnome.org/libnm/stable/usage.html

Comment: @GarfieldCat   Я разобрался уже что к чему - QT своим препроцессором залазит в хедер библиотеки и портит его. Правда я не знаю пока как ему это запретить